# Is it possible to search some word in js files only of certain project?

Tags: atom-editor, adobe-brackets

I am using Brackets and Atom for front-end development.

I am trying to achieve this:
1. Search the certain work Ex: "Testing"
2. That word is in so many files which are html,javascript and others.
3. I want only *.js files to display the results.

There are 100s of files, it is difficult to manually do it.

What I'm trying to achieve?
I want to search all Regex written for the form validation in this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is.

1. First `ctrl` + `shift` + `F`
2. In the first input box (Find in Project), enter the word you want to search.
3. In the last input box(File/Directory Pattern), enter Projectname,*.js

Note: ProjectName is case sensitive.